# Xcode 10.2 – Swift 5 enum with associated values enters incorrect case

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift5, xcode10.2

I just updated one of my projects to Swift 5 and have a pretty weird occurrence.
I'm using a `GKStateMachine` to handle states for a game. When entering a state I also set the value of an enum to the related case for cleaner communication to the outside.
Now after the update to Swift 5 this isn't properly working anymore.

**An example**

This is the enum:

```
public enum GameState: Equatable {
    case setup
    case preparing
    case calibrating(calibrationState: GameCalibrationState)
    case lostTrack
    case readyToPlay
    case running(canSkipItems: Bool)
    case handlingTask
    case paused
    case gameOver
}
```

Now in the GameOver State of the State Machine I do the following:

```
class GameOverState: GKState {
    weak var gameManager: GameManagable?

    init(gameManager: GameManagable) {
        self.gameManager = gameManager
    }

    override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {
        // Entered game over state and now trying to set game manager state to .gameOver:
        gameManager?.currentState = .gameOver
        // The currentState property state should now be set to .gameOver but is .lostTrack instead
    }

    override func isValidNextState(_ stateClass: AnyClass) -> Bool {
        switch stateClass {
        case is GameSetupState.Type:
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

It enters the state and in the »didEnter(from previousState: GKState?)« method I set the currentState of my GameManager object to .gameOver – so far so good. But somehow this isn't working as it get's set to .lostTrack instead. The same is happening for the Paused State with the .paused case.

And the console output while running:
[image: console output]

Interestingly when I change the order of cases in the enum it also sets it to another case. Beside .paused and .gameOver all the other ones seem to work and get set correctly.
This definitely worked before and I have no idea what could be going on. At this point it seems to me like a system bug

A screenshot of the relevant definitions in the GameManager:
[image: GameManager]

Sidefact: It also works when I get rid of the associated values of the enum cases.

Same outcome in both Xcode 10.2 and Xcode 10.2.1

Example Playground that reproduces the issue:
https://www.sendspace.com/file/qudvzt

Comment: Any small reproducationpath that I can drag and drop into xcode and get the same behaviour?

Comment: What if you take away `Equatable` conformance? Also, can we see the definition of `gameManager`?

Comment: Same thing when I remove the Equatable conformance. The GameManager class is a little too complex to post everything and contains some code I can't share here. I attached a screenshot of the relevant definitions. Can see if I can put together a playground to reproduce the problem, but the project itself is quite big.

Comment: Please replace that screenshot with the actual code (as text), just like you did for the other code.

Comment: I recently found a compiler crash when using an enum with mixed cases with and without associated values. There may be some bugs in Swift 5 compiler. You should better send a bug repost through [Repost Bugs](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) of Apple's or [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org/).

Comment: I've created and attached a playground that reproduces the issue: https://www.sendspace.com/file/qudvzt – as mentioned removing the associated type solves the problem.